# Slim 3 sending data between middlewares

Tags: php, slim-3

I want to send data between one middleware to other. As one middleware passes, I want to add some JSON response and pass to next middleware. What can be the best possible way to do it in Slim 3.

For example:

```
$app->post('/main_route/','reset_password')->add('middleware2')->add('middleware1');
```

How can I send some JSON data from middleware1 to middleware2 and then to main route?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html#passing-variables-from-middleware) explain how to do this:

In the first middleware you can do:

```
$request = $request->withAttribute('foo', 'bar');
```

In the second middleware ...

```
$foo = $request->getAttribute('foo');
```

Comment: It says passing variables, is it desirable to pass a full JSON response in value.??

Comment: Please elaborate what you're trying to do in your question.

Comment: I am actually passing a JSON feed generated from one middleware to next and so on.. now is it desirable to do that with these functions? will it affect performance?.